# android.os.BadParcelableException (Proguard + extend ResultReceiver)

Tags: android

I have simple class extending ResultReceiver that I use to communicate between a service and some activities:

```
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.os.Handler; 
import android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver;

@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
public class DataSyncResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

    private Receiver mReceiver;

    public DataSyncResultReceiver(Receiver receiver, Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
        setReceiver(receiver);
    }

    public interface Receiver {
        void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData);
    }

    public void setReceiver(Receiver receiver) {
        mReceiver = receiver;
    }

    public boolean hasReceiver() {
        return mReceiver != null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        if (mReceiver == null) {
            Log.e("DataSyncResultReceiver", "Receiver is null");
        } else {
            mReceiver.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine If don't use proguard with minifyEnabled true
But if I use it i get the following crash a bit after launch:

> android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a
>   Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class
>   DataSyncResultReceiver

I tried the following proguard-rules, without success:

```
-keep class **$$Parcelable { *; }

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
   public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Could anyone help me on this one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding

```
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver
```